# remove all duplicate records efficiently

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have a file which might be **30+GB** or more. And each line in this file is called a record and is composed of *2 cols*, which goes like this

> id1 id2

All of this 2 ids are integers (32-bit). My job is to write a program to remove all the duplicate record, make the record unique, finally output the unique id2 into a file.

There is some constraints, **30G memory** is allowed at most, and better get the job done efficiently by a **non-multithread/process program**.

Initially I came up with an idea: because of the memory constraints, I decided to read the file **n** times, each only keep in memory those record with `id1 % n = i (i = 0,1,2,..,n-1)`. The data structure I use is a `std::map<int, std::set<int> >`, it takes id1 as key, and put id2 in id1's `std::set`.

This way, memory constraints will not be violated, but it's quite slow. I think it's because as the `std::map` and `std::set` grows larger, the insertion speed goes down. Moreover, I need to read the file n times, when each round is done, I gotta clear the `std::map` for next round which also cost some time.

I also tried **hash**, but it doesn't satisfy me either, which I thought there might be too many collisions even with **300W** buckets.

So, I post my problem here, help you guys can offer me any better data structure or algorithm.

Thanks a lot.

PS

Scripts (shell, python) are desired, if it can do it efficiently.

Comment: Do you have to do it as a C++ program? Can't you use tools like `sort` and `uniq` (assuming Linux) on the shell?

Comment: @jogojapan, yes, if it is efficient.

Comment: Is a duplicate defined as _identical in both columns_, or _identical in the first column only_?

Comment: @jogojapan, a dup is defined as identical in both cols.

Comment: What do you mean by "finally output the unique id2 into a file" ?

Comment: @PuraVida, make all the records unique, then write each record's id2 into a file.

Comment: So you might have duplicate id2 in the output?  And you don't want id1 printed to the output? To clarify, if you have 4 billion unique records, with id1 in the range 0 to pow(2,32)-1 and with id2 equal to zero for all then what is the correct output?

Comment: What kind of hash did you use?  `std::unordered_multimap<int,int>` ?

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky, I used id1+id2 as the hashkey, but its efficiency is not good. I presume it's because records in the file results into a lot of collision.

Comment: @Alcott - If you meant  sum of id1 and id2, then you can decrease collisions if you use `std::pair<int,int>`.  I don't believe collisions is the cause of slow downs.  Why do you think collisions are the cause? And I was not asking what you used for key, I was asking what data structure you used for the hash.

Answer (score 8):

Unless I overlooked a requirement, it should be possible to do this on the Linux shell as

```
sort -u inputfile > outputfile
```

Many implementations enable you to use `sort` in a parallelised manner as well:

```
sort --parallel=4 -u inputfile > outputfile
```

for up to four parallel executions.

Note that `sort` might use a lot of space in `/tmp` temporarily. If you run out of disk space there, you may use the `-T` option to point it to an alternative place on disk to use as temporary directory.

---

(Edit:) A few remarks about efficiency:

- A significant portion of the time spent during execution (of any solution to your problem) will be spent on IO, something that `sort` is highly optimised for.
- Unless you have extremely much RAM, your solution is likely to end up performing some of the work on disk (just like `sort`). Again, optimising this means a lot of work, while for `sort` all of that work has been done.
- One disadvantage of `sort` is that it operates on string representations of the input lines. If you were to write your own code, one thing you could do (similar to what you suggesed already) is to convert the input lines to 64-bit integers and hash them. If you have enough RAM, that may be a way to beat `sort` in terms of speed, if you get IO and integer conversions to be really fast. I suspect it may not be worth the effort as `sort` is easy to use and – I think – fast enough.

Comment: Upvoted. But do you really think it can do the job efficiently (cost  less than 30 mins)?

Comment: +1 for exhibiting self-control and utilizing someone else's hard work. Mark of an outstanding engineer (and before anyone asks, i'm NOT being  sarcastic).

Comment: `sort` has a `-u` option to produce unique output, you don't need to pipe to `uniq`. This should be significantly faster, too, since it only has to sort the unique elements rather than all of them.

Comment: @Alcott Let's just say it is _very_ efficient. There are certainly ways to beat it, especially as you are dealing with integers, but these Unix tools would in any case be my first attempt. Easy enough to try anyway.

Comment: @Barmar is right. (I put `uniq` separately out of habit; I am doing this a lot using the `-u` and `-d` options of `uniq`, which are not directly supported by `sort` But in this case, `sort -u` is optimal.) I'll edit the post.

Comment: Yes, but I just found out I don't have `--parallel` option for `sort`, why?]

Answer (score 1):

I just don't think you can do this efficiently without using a bunch of disk.  Any form of data structure will introduce so much memory and/or storage overhead that your algorithm will suffer.  So I would expect a sorting solution to be best here.

I reckon you can sort large chunks of the file at a time, and then merge (*ie* from merge-sort) those chunks after.  After sorting a chunk, obviously it has to go back to disk.  You could just replace the data in the input file (assuming it's binary), or write to a temporary file.

As far as the records, you just have a bunch of 64-bit values.  With 30GB RAM, you can hold almost 4 billion records at a time.  That's pretty sweet.  You could sort that many in-place with quicksort, or half that many with mergesort.  You probably won't get a contiguous block of memory that size.  So you're going to have to break it up.  That will make quicksort a little trickier, so you might want to use mergesort in RAM as well.

During the final merge it's trivial to discard duplicates.  The merge might be entirely file-based, but at worst you'll use an amount of disk equivalent to twice the number of records in the input file (one file for scratch and one file for output).  If you can use the input file as scratch, then you have not exceeded your RAM limits OR your disk limits (if any).

I think the key here is the requirement that it shouldn't be multithreaded.  That lends itself well to disk-based storage.  The bulk of your time is going to be spent on disk access.  So you wanna make sure you do that as efficiently as possible.  In particular, when you're merge-sorting you want to minimize the amount of seeking.  You have large amounts of memory as buffer, so I'm sure you can make that very efficient.

So let's say your file is 60GB (and I assume it's binary) so there's around 8 billion records.  If you're merge-sorting in RAM, you can process 15GB at a time.  That amounts to reading and (over)writing the file once.  Now there are four chunks.  If you want to do pure merge-sort then you always deal with just two arrays.  That means you read and write the file two more times: once to merge each 15GB chunk into 30GB, and one final merge on those (including discarding of duplicates).

I don't think that's too bad.  Three times in and out.  If you figure out a nice way to quicksort then you can probably do this with one fewer pass through the file.  I imagine a data structure like `deque` would work well, as it can handle non-contiguous chunks of memory...  But you'd probably wanna build your own and finely tune your sorting algorithm to exploit it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `std::map<int, std::set<int> >` use `std::unordered_multimap<int,int>`.  If you can not use C++11 - write your own.

The `std::map` is node based and it calls malloc on each insertion, this is probably why it is slow. With unodered map (hash table), if you know number of records, you can pre-allocate.  Even if you don't, number of mallocs will be `O(log N)` instead of `O(N)` with `std::map`.

I can bet this will be several times faster and more memory efficient  than using external `sort -u`.

Answer (score 1):

This approach may help when there are not too many duplicate records in the file.

1st pass. Allocate most of the memory for [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). Hash every pair from input file and put the result into Bloom filter. Write each duplicate, found by Bloom filter into temporary file (this file will also contain some amount of false positives, which are not duplicates).

2nd pass. Load temporary file and construct a map from its records. Key is `std::pair<int,int>`, value is a boolean flag. This map may be implemented either as std::unordered_map/boost::unordered_map, or as std::map.

3rd pass. Read input file again, search each record in the map, output its `id2` if either not found or flag is not yet set, then set this flag.